# where did storm BaseBasicBolt handle ack() func?

Tags: apache-storm

As we know, when using `BaseBasicBolt`, we don't need to call `ack()` function.

But when I go through the code of `BaeBasicBolt`,`IBasicCode`, can't find any implementation of code.

So, I am wondering how the `ack()` method is being called in `BasicBolt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found it.

when `TopologyBuilder.setBolt()` is done, there is a `BasicBoltExecutor` handing `ack` and `fail` logic.